# C#. How can i store incorrect answers to use them after the user has finish the quiz?

Tags: c#

I need this quiz to store the questions that have been answered incorrectly by the user and then at the end of the quiz, the program will give the user the option to review the questions that were answered incorrectly and do them again. Can someone please explain to me how to do this or point me in the right direction?

Thank You in Advance.

This is what I have so far.

```
enter code here

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Quiz
{
    public class User
    {
        public static string name;
        public User()
        {
        string quiz = "This Quiz consists of 10 questions. \r\n5 True or False and 5 Multiple choice.";
        string user1 = "Please enter your name (last, first) and press ENTER.";
        string heading1 = String.Format("{0}\r\n{1}\r\n{2}", heading, quiz, user1);
        Console.WriteLine(heading1);
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        string introduction = "Welcom to the Aeronautical Knowledge Quiz " + name + "!" + "\r\nNOTE: This quiz is case sensitive.";
        string enter = "Press ENTER to begin the quiz.";
        string introduction1 = String.Format("{0}\r\n{1}", introduction, enter);
        Console.WriteLine(introduction1);
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

    }

}

public class Quiz
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        User user1 = new User();


        string[] questions = { "The fuselage is the center structure of an aircraft and provides the connection for the wings and tail. \r\nTrue or False?",
            "Rolling is the action on the lateral axis of an aircraft. \r\nTrue or False?",

            "Drag is the name of the force that resists movement of an aircraft through the air. \r\nTrue or False?",

            "Flaps are attached to the trailing edge of a wing structure and only increases drag. \r\nTrue or False?",

            "Powerplant or engine produces thrust to propel an aircraft. \r\nTrue or False?",

            "Which of the following are part of an aircraft primary flight controls? \r\na.Aileron. \r\nb.Rudder. \r\nc.Elevators. \r\nd. All of the above.",
            "The Fuel-air control unit of a reciprocating engine? \r\na.Sends fuel to the piston chamber. \r\nb.Sends air to the piston chamber. \r\nc.Controls the mixture of air and fuel. \r\nd.Meters the quantity of fuel.",

            "Which of the following is the main source of electrical power when starting an aircraft? \r\na.Primary Bus. \r\nb.Avionics Bus. \r\nc.Battery. \r\nd.GPU (ground power unit)",

            "The reservoir of a hydraulic system is used for? \r\na.Store and collect fluid from a hydraulic system. \r\nb.Lubricate components when needed. \r\nc.Keep the fluid clean. \r\nd.All of the above.",

            "Flying into fog can create? \r\na.Narrows the runway. \r\nb.An aircraft to stall. \r\nc.An illusion of pitching up. \r\nd.A stressful environment for the Pilot and Co-pilot." };

        string[] answers = { "True", "True", "True", "False", "True", "d", "c", "c", "a", "c" };
        string studentAnswer;
        int correctAnswer = 0;
        int qcounter = 0;
        int questionNum = 0;
        int answerNum = 0;
        while (questionNum < questions.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(questions[questionNum], 10, 30);
            studentAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
            if (studentAnswer == answers[answerNum])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
                questionNum++;
                answerNum++;
                correctAnswer++;
                qcounter++;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect.");
                questionNum++;
                answerNum++;
                qcounter++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER for Next question.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();

        }
        Console.WriteLine(User.name + ", Your final score is: " + correctAnswer + "/" + qcounter + ".");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to EXIT");

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: instead of an array of questions create a question class object to hold the question and other attributes and have a list/array of questions, then you can include a flag for correct/incorrect in the question object.

Comment: You have a whole bunch of `Quiz` related stuff in your `User` class. You might consider separating that out.

Comment: Rather than keeping synchronized parallel arrays (questions and answers), why not create a `class` to keep these two values together?

Comment: Feel sorry for your users who have to type `True` (for example) in exactly the casing youve chosent to get the right answer.

Comment: I would create a class for `QuizItem` that has properties for `Question`, `Answer`, `Choices`, `UserResponse`, and `Result` amongst others. Then populate a list of them, present them to the user in a loop, and at the end you can filter them on `QuizItems.Where(quizItem => quizItem.Result == false);` to get the ones they missed.

Comment: Why do you need separate index for questionNum and answerNum.   Why the repeated code.   for (int i = 0; i < question.length; i++)  Store the incorrect i in a List<int>

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach, which is to create a class that represents a Question (I called it `QuizItem`, since it also has the answer), and which has properties to represent the question, a list of possible answers, and the index of the correct answer; and which has the ability to ask the question and get (and store) the user's response.

This may seem like a little more work up front, but it makes asking/answering and presenting result data pretty easy at the end:

```
public class QuizItem
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public List<string> Choices { get; set; }
    public int CorrectChoiceIndex { get; set; }
    public string UserResponse { get; private set; }
    public bool Result { get; private set; }

    public bool AskQuestion()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Question);

        for (int i = 0; i < Choices.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. {Choices[i]}");
        }

        int choice;
        do
        {
            Console.Write($"Enter response (1 - {Choices.Count}): ");
        } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice) ||
                    choice < 1 || choice > Choices.Count);

        Result = choice - 1 == CorrectChoiceIndex;
        UserResponse = Choices[choice - 1];

        Console.WriteLine(Result ? "Correct!" : "Incorrect.");
        Console.WriteLine();

        return Result;
    }
}
```

Now we can populate a list of these questions. I put this part in a separate method just to make the main code cleaner:

```
public static List<QuizItem> GetQuizItems()
{
    return new List<QuizItem>
    {
        new QuizItem
        {
            Question = "The fuselage is the center structure of an aircraft and " + 
                "provides the connection for the wings and tail.",
            Choices = new List<string> {"True", "False"},
            CorrectChoiceIndex = 0
        },
        new QuizItem
        {
            Question = "Rolling is the action on the lateral axis of an aircraft.",
            Choices = new List<string> {"True", "False"},
            CorrectChoiceIndex = 0
        },
        new QuizItem
        {
            Question = "Drag is the name of the force that resists movement of an  " + 
                "aircraft through the air.",
            Choices = new List<string> {"True", "False"},
            CorrectChoiceIndex = 0
        },
        new QuizItem
        {
            Question = "Flaps are attached to the trailing edge of a wing structure  " + 
                "and only increases drag.",
            Choices = new List<string> {"True", "False"},
            CorrectChoiceIndex = 1
        },
        new QuizItem
        {
            Question = "Powerplant or engine produces thrust to propel an aircraft.",
            Choices = new List<string> {"True", "False"},
            CorrectChoiceIndex = 0
        },
        new QuizItem
        {
            Question = "Which of the following are part of an aircraft " + 
                "primary flight controls?",
            Choices = new List<string>
                {"Aileron", "Rudder", "Elevators", "All of the above"},
            CorrectChoiceIndex = 3
        },
        new QuizItem
        {
            Question = "The Fuel-air control unit of a reciprocating engine?",
            Choices = new List<string>
                {
                    "Sends fuel to the piston chamber",
                    "Sends air to the piston chamber",
                    "Controls the mixture of air and fuel",
                    "Meters the quantity of fuel"
                },
            CorrectChoiceIndex = 2
        },
        new QuizItem
        {
            Question = "Which of the following is the main source of electrical power " + 
                "when starting an aircraft?",
            Choices = new List<string> 
                {"Primary Bus", "Avionics Bus", "Battery", "GPU (ground power unit)"},
            CorrectChoiceIndex = 2
        },
        new QuizItem
        {
            Question = "The reservoir of a hydraulic system is used for what?",
            Choices = new List<string>
                {
                    "Store and collect fluid from a hydraulic system",
                    "Lubricate components when needed",
                    "Keep the fluid clean",
                    "All of the above"
                },
            CorrectChoiceIndex = 0
        },
        new QuizItem
        {
            Question = "Flying into fog can cause what?",
            Choices = new List<string>
                {
                    "Narrowing of the runway",
                    "An aircraft to stall",
                    "An illusion of pitching up",
                    "A stressful environment for the Pilot and Co-pilot"
                },
            CorrectChoiceIndex = 2
        }
    };
}
```

Now we can ask our questions and get our results really easily, as well as re-ask the missed questions:

```
private static void Main(string[] cmdArgs)
{
    var quizItems = GetQuizItems();

    foreach (var quizItem in quizItems)
    {
        quizItem.AskQuestion();
    }

    var correctCount = quizItems.Count(item => item.Result);

    Console.WriteLine($"You got {correctCount} out of {quizItems.Count} questions correct!");

    Console.WriteLine("\nLet's review the questions you missed:\n");

    foreach (var quizItem in quizItems.Where(item => !item.Result))
    {
        quizItem.AskQuestion();
    }

    correctCount = quizItems.Count(item => item.Result);
    var percentCorrect = 100.0 * correctCount / quizItems.Count;

    Console.WriteLine($"Your final score was {correctCount} out " +
                        $"of {quizItems.Count}, or {percentCorrect}%!");

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

Comment: @Matt Yes, I know...this does that, just after the line that says, "Let's review the questions you missed". Is there something missing?

Comment: Just my eyes apparently

Answer (score 1):

**Steps**:

- Declare studentAnswer empty array(Use the same length of answers array)
- Use the same index of answers array and store the **console.readline** input

This is the part of the **Code** to edit ( It will store all the answer )

```
//Declare the array with answer
string[] answers = { "True", "True", "True", "False", "True", "d", "c", "c", "a", "c" };
string[] studentAnswer = new string[answers.Length]; 
//Use the array in you while loop
while (questionNum < questions.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(questions[questionNum], 10, 30);
            //Here you store the student answer
            studentAnswer[answerNum] = Console.ReadLine();
            //Here you check the student answer using the same index of answer array
            if (studentAnswer[answerNum] == answers[answerNum])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
                questionNum++;
                answerNum++;
                correctAnswer++;
                qcounter++;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect.");
                //Remove these increment and the question will be the same in the next loop cycle
                questionNum++; // remove
                answerNum++; // remove
                qcounter++; // remove
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER for Next question.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
        }
```

**EDIT AFTER MATT COMMENT:**

Is better to use the `.ToLower()` function, so the character will be converted to lower case, and the student can type both(lower and upper case) without getting false result.

To do this you have to edit the if line:

```
if (studentAnswer[answerNum].ToLower() == answers[answerNum].ToLower())
```

**EDIT AFTER PAPARAZZO COMMENT:**

Here you store all the incorrect answer:

```
//Declare the array with answer
string[] answers = { "True", "True", "True", "False", "True", "d", "c", "c", "a", "c" };

string[] studentAnswer = new string[answers.Length];
//You can use list
List<string> incorrectAnswer = new List<string>();
//Use the array in you while loop
while (questionNum < questions.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(questions[questionNum], 10, 30);
            //Here you store the student answer
            studentAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
            //Here you check the student answer using the same index of answer array
            if (studentAnswer.ToLower() == answers[answerNum].ToLower())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
                questionNum++;
                answerNum++;
                correctAnswer++;
                qcounter++;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect.");
                incorrectAnswer.Add(studentAnswer)
                //Remove these increment and the question will be the same in the next loop cycle
                questionNum++; // remove
                answerNum++; // remove
                qcounter++; // remove
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER for Next question.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
        }
```

Comment: Damn, this is pretty much my solution.. with one slight change `studentAnswer[answerNum] == answers[answerNum]` is `studentAnswers[answerNum].ToLower() == correctAnswers[answerNum].ToLower()`

Comment: Your solution is better, you convert to lower case, so the can type with lower and upper case letter without getting error. You can improve my answer editing it if you want

Answer (score 0):

I was bored too:

```
public class Quiz
{

    public static void Main()
    {

        Quizard QuizGame = new Quizard();


        QuizGame.Questions.Add(new QuestionObject {
            Question = "The fuselage is the center structure of an aircraft and provides the connection for the wings and tail?",
            Options = new List<string> { "True", "False" },
            CorrectAnswer = "a"
        });

        QuizGame.Questions.Add(new QuestionObject {
            Question = "Rolling is the action on the lateral axis of an aircraft?",
            Options = new List<string> { "True", "False" },
            CorrectAnswer = "a"
        });

        QuizGame.Questions.Add(new QuestionObject {
            Question = "Which of the following are part of an aircraft primary flight controls?",
            Options = new List<string> { "Primary Bus", "Avionics Bus", "Battery", "GPU (ground power unit)" },
            CorrectAnswer = "d"
        });

        QuizGame.Questions.Add(new QuestionObject {
            Question = "The Fuel-air control unit of a reciprocating engine?",
            Options = new List<string> { "Sends fuel to the piston chamber", "Sends air to the piston chamber", "Controls the mixture of air and fuel", "Meters the quantity of fuel" },
            CorrectAnswer = "c"
        });



        Display(QuizGame.Questions);

        while (true) {
            if (QuizGame.Questions.Where(x => x.Correct == false) != null) {
                Console.WriteLine(QuizGame.Questions.Where(x => x.Correct == true).Count() + " out of " + QuizGame.Questions.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to try again? Y/N");
                if (Console.ReadLine().ToLower() == "y") {

                    Display(QuizGame.Questions.Where(x => x.Correct == false).ToList());
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        void Display(List<QuestionObject> questions)
        {
            string[] marker = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
            foreach (var question in questions) {
                Console.WriteLine(question.Question);
                for (int i = 0; i < question.Options.Count; i++) {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{marker[i]}. {question.Options[i]}");
                }
                Console.Write(">>");
                question.GivenAnswer = Console.ReadLine();

                if (question.GivenAnswer.ToLower() == question.CorrectAnswer.ToLower()) {
                    question.Correct = true;
                } else {
                    question.Correct = false;
                }

                Console.Clear();
            }         
        }
    }        
}


public class QuestionObject{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
    public List<string> Options { get; set; }
    public string GivenAnswer { get; set; }
    public bool Correct { get; set; }        
}

public class Quizard
{
    private List<QuestionObject> m_Questions = new List<QuestionObject>();
    public List<QuestionObject> Questions {
        get { return m_Questions; }
        set {
            Questions = value;
        }
    }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Didn't add all the questions, didn't do any bounds check either so if you have more than 4 questions it's gunna fall over unless you add to the `marker` array

Answer (score -1):

Just use a List for incorrect.

And you should test the response for valid input.  What if they enter f?

This is a more direct approach.

```
public static void Quiz()
{
    string[] questions = { "The fuselage is the center structure of an aircraft and provides the connection for the wings and tail. \r\nTrue or False?",
    "Rolling is the action on the lateral axis of an aircraft. \r\nTrue or False?",

    "Drag is the name of the force that resists movement of an aircraft through the air. \r\nTrue or False?",

    "Flaps are attached to the trailing edge of a wing structure and only increases drag. \r\nTrue or False?",

    "Powerplant or engine produces thrust to propel an aircraft. \r\nTrue or False?",

    "Which of the following are part of an aircraft primary flight controls? \r\na.Aileron. \r\nb.Rudder. \r\nc.Elevators. \r\nd. All of the above.",
    "The Fuel-air control unit of a reciprocating engine? \r\na.Sends fuel to the piston chamber. \r\nb.Sends air to the piston chamber. \r\nc.Controls the mixture of air and fuel. \r\nd.Meters the quantity of fuel.",

    "Which of the following is the main source of electrical power when starting an aircraft? \r\na.Primary Bus. \r\nb.Avionics Bus. \r\nc.Battery. \r\nd.GPU (ground power unit)",

    "The reservoir of a hydraulic system is used for? \r\na.Store and collect fluid from a hydraulic system. \r\nb.Lubricate components when needed. \r\nc.Keep the fluid clean. \r\nd.All of the above." };
    string[] answers = { "True", "True", "True", "False", "True", "d", "c", "c", "a", "c" };
    string studentAnswer;
    List<int> incorrectAnswers = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < questions.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(questions[i], 10, 30);
        studentAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
        if (studentAnswer == answers[i])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect.");
            incorrectAnswers.Add(i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER for Next question.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
    }
}
```